# jQuery handling events on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, webforms, bind

I have an RMA form that I've been able to add fields dynamically, but having trouble it being able to handle events (like click, change).

I'm adding the fields by using the `.appendTo("#container");` and incrementing the NAME parameter using a counter, so that when the user hits Submit--I'll get 'Category1: blah' 'Category2: blahblah' 'Category3: something_else', etc.

The problem is when I add more fields (like a dropdown box) dynamically, the events don't follow.  I have 3 drop downs [category] [subcategory] [model].  When I select a category:

```
jQuery('#cat').bind("change", function()
    {
        jQuery('#subcat').empty();
        jQuery('#subcat').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        jQuery('#model').empty();
        jQuery('#model').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        LoadSeries(jQuery(this).val()); // I do a .removeAttr('disabled'); in here for #subcat

    });
```

In the above code, I tried adding `jQuery('#cat'+counter).bind("change", function() { ...` but I think that event will only fire if I change the [category] and hit the add button simultaneously.

I tried using .live but I'm not sure how to get it to work with added elements with different class/name parameters (cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5...)

Would I need separate functions as well? (LoadSeries2, LoadSeries3, etc.) for the amount of fields that are added?

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT: Some of the HTML code to show radio buttons above the [category] [subcategory] [model] drop downs.  This is for the user to select whether it's going to be a return or an exchange.

```
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('
    <div class="item'+counter+'"><br/>
    <table width="820" border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border: 1px; border-color: #000;">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div align="center" style="font-size: 14px;">
            <input type="radio" class="radioBtn'+counter+'" name="Return_Exchange'+counter+'" value="Return" selected="selected">Return
            <input type="radio" class="radioBtn'+counter+'" name="Return_Exchange'+counter+'" value="Exchange">Exchange</div>
...
```

Comment: could you show some HTML if possible? I know there's a lot of dynamic creation going on.

Comment: @hunter the HTML is _extremely_ lengthy, but here's some of it... This is on top of the [category] [subcategory] [model] for the users to indicate whether it's going to be an return or an exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) method or in your case the [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method might be best. Combined with the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`^=`) you should be good to go...

```
$("#container").delegate("[id^='cat']", "change", function() {
    $("#subcat, #model").empty().attr("disabled", true);
    LoadSeries($(this).val());
});
```

---

jQuery using `on`

```
$("#container").on("change", "[id^='cat']", function() {
    $("#subcat, #model").empty().attr("disabled", true);
    LoadSeries($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about delegate()! Thanks for the tidbit. :)

Comment: Is there are a similar solution for current versions of jQuery, since `delegate()` and `live()` have been shunted out the door, and `on()` doesn't seem to bind events to elements added in the future. http://jsfiddle.net/9C4Kb/

Comment: @jegesh added an example using `on`. `on` will work on future elements since it's applying the change event to `#container` element

Comment: It's very important to stress that the future application of `on()` is only effective when binding it to a parent element, and then filtering with a selector. That's the point I didn't understand, and got quite hung up on.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an additional class specifically for items that will need to be bound to this event, etc...

```
<input class="cat3 eventClass" />
```

Then just use `.live()` to bind any existing or future `$('.eventClass')` elements to the event

Answer (score 0):

You can use a starts with selector along with live
Try this:

```
jQuery('[id^=cat]').live("change", function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
    jQuery('#subcat' + id).empty();
    jQuery('#subcat' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    jQuery('#model' + id).empty();
    jQuery('#model' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    LoadSeries(jQuery(this).val()); // I do a .removeAttr('disabled'); in here for #subcat      
});
```